# Class Names Are Only Accepted if Annotation Processing Is Explicitly Requested Java

Tags: java, github, download

So I found a [Tower Defense game on Github](https://github.com/shaon0000/Tower-Defense) that I'm planning to use so I can see how this person made the game and use that info to make my own. In their readme file, they say

> INSTALLING/STARTING THE GAME:
>
> command line instruction:
>
> javac BattleMap
>
> java BattleMap
>
> The first line compiles all the source code. The second line launches the java application.

So in Command prompt I type:

> javac BattleMap

and it doesnt work. It says, of course, "class names are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested"

So every other topic I've found on this seems to suggest adding .java at the end, and that magically fixes it. Then people also say, even though the first answer worked, to make sure you're typing .java and not .Java

So of course I tried typing

> javac BattleMap.java

and it still says "Class Names Are Only Accepted if Annotation Processing Is Explicitly Requested Java". I even tried .Java and instead of javac just typing java BattleMap and all the combinations of everything I could find, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to open this stupid little file that I downloaded off the internet. I'm running Windows 7, CMD is being Run as Administrator, and it doesn't work. Can anyone help? More importantly, can anyone help *without* marking this as a duplicate? Because that would be great.

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". What happens precisely?

Comment: Works for me (`javac BattleMap.java`).

Comment: @JBNizet oh sorry what I mean is that it supplies me with the "class names are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested" error.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the Zip from Git opened the command window in folder where the BattleMap class is and typed in command window

> javac Xlint- BattleMap.java

next it shows some warnings and then I typed

> java BattleMap

The game runs properly for me.

[image]

Comment: For me, when doing this it says, "javac: invalid flag: Xlint-"                                I try ignoring the errors and type `java BattleMap` but it says, "Error: Could not find or load main class BattleMap"

Comment: you downloaded from git the zip and you extracted the folder?

Comment: Yes. I wish there was something else to add to this comment but there isn't.